# How to select CUDA compiler?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, compiling, cuda

I'm currently working with CUDA Version: 10.2. However, I need to install also a previous version of CUDA (8.0) as I need it to run some old code with TensorFlow 1.13.

I'm following [this](https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/multiple-version-of-cuda-libraries-on-the-same-machine-b9502d50ae77) guide. In the end, I wish to have two "conda" environments, one for each CUDA, that I will select when activating the environment.

After downloading the desired CUDA [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive), I've tried installing it, as:

> sudo sh cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux-run --silent --toolkit
>   --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-8.0

However, the installation fails, with error:

```
Error: unsupported compiler: 10.1.0. Use --override to override this check.
```

How can I select the compiler to use for installing CUDA 8.0? I don't want to remove the current one.

Thank you :)

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running, and what old compiler do you need?  CUDA 8 may need a really old compiler not even offered by the latest releases.  I avoid all the "CUDA install" problems by just unpacking the Intel debs locally, then adding links to the old compilers in the cuda/bin,

Comment: Thanks for the help. I use Ubuntu 18.04.4. If I'm not wrong, with CUDA 8 I should use gcc 8, though I don't have it installed anymore (I'm not sure how to do it)

Comment: Better check, I have a CUDA 8 install with a  gcc-5 link (and gcc-7 as default).  Just use sudo apt-get gcc-5 (and the ar-5, nm-5, and ranlib-5 if they don't get brought in automatically), then add their links to cuda/bin.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not very familiar with this. I guess this won't override the other compilers, but will it change the default compiler? and, once installed gcc-5, how can I tell the system to use gcc-5 instead of another compiler? Thank you again for the help :)

Comment: The Intel installation instructions have you modify your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH putting the cuda/bin and cuda/lib64 first, so the gcc link to the selected cuda compiler will be found before the system one in /usr/bin.